# How does cassandra reacts to a region failure in Multi-Region setup

Tags: amazon-web-services, cassandra, nosql, cassandra-2.0, cassandra-3.0

I am trying to understand cassandra in multi-region setup.
Suppose I have a Cassandra cluster setup in 3 AWS Regions(A,B and C) each and if a region goes down(Region C).
How does an outage in entire region affect Cassandra queries.

1. If my reads and writes are configured at CL = LOCAL_QUORUM does the outage impact transaction in region A and B.
2. If reads and write are at CL = EACH_QUORUM, will reads/writes fail in regions A and B.
3. What if Region C is undergoing planned maintenance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend you to look into [DSE Architecture Guide](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/6.7/dse-arch/datastax_enterprise/dbInternals/dbIntTOC.html) that covers how Cassandra works.  You need to remember several things, like, that all writes are sent to all replicas in all DCs, independent of consistency level, and that when node is down for short period of time (< 3 hours by default) other nodes will collect so-called hints that will replay changes when node is back.

The effect of outage will depend on the consistency levels that you're using, so answering to your questions:

1. No, it shouldn't affect DCs A & B, until you have `read_repair_chance` or  `dclocal_repair_chance` set to non-zero - in later case you may hit [CASSANDRA-9753](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-9753), that could lead to sending requests to remote DCs;
2. yes, read and writes will fail with `EACH_QUORUM`. But you can use `QUORUM` with 3 DCs (depends on RF in each DC of course), and allow one to go down completely;
3. it's the same as failure if you shutdown the full region, but if you do one by one machine, then it may work.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Will this behavior remain same for Active-active, multi-Region setup where  cassandra rings are deployed separately in different regions and are peered to replicate data between rings.

Comment: what do you mean by separate rings? Every DC is a separate ring inside the cluster

Comment: By separate Ring , I mean one independent cluster per region. Each cluster in the region is peered so the data is synced on the cluster in all regions. I am referring https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/best-practices-for-running-apache-cassandra-on-amazon-ec2/  Active-Active muli-region setup. Please let me know if you are referring to same setup. Thanks!

Comment: In that case it’s a single cluster. Indepedent clusters could be synced only with something like DSE advanced replication

Comment: So in that case(Active-Active Multi region setup) will the write with CL=EACH_QUORUM go to each remote region as well? Thanks for answering my naive questions.

Comment: Writes are going to every DC independent of the consistency level. CL just means how many answers we need to wait for... in each quorum this means that quorum in each region must answer

Comment: Got it. So single region independent  cluster  setup replicated to  independent clusters in other regions  is similar to one cluster setup spread across multiple regions? Or are they totally different. Please share any links that you may have related to cassandra setup in multi-region environment.

Comment: In Cassandra every cluster is independent. You may have multi region setup inside one cluster with DC per region... if you have one cluster with multiple DCs, then just follow my answer. I really recommend to read arch guide